# How to read capacitor code u10j63?

Tags: capacitor

I need to find these capacitor immediately. How to read these values? I am pretty sure they are metalized polyester film capacitor. But I don't know what values they are? Capacitors look like this.

[image]

Comment: A picture would help. But I think I already know but I'm not telling... immediately.

Comment: 18 minutes later and I guess "immediately" has slipped a bit.

Comment: By immediately I mean within an hour i guess :D

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll answer in 1 hour then ;-) Unless you pay me of course, then you can have the answer now. And of course I need to see a photo / picture first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Rempelbekkie says, it is a 0.1µF, 63Volts, 5% tolerance capacitor.

In case you have more capacitors to check, [here is a link to a complete chart.](http://de.tdk.eu/blob/187716/download/4/pdf-markingandorderingcodesystem.pdf)

Extract:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's a 100 nF (= 0.1 uF) capacitor, 63 V